# What equipment can be used to measure sound equipment quality?

Tags: sound, equipment

My audiologist has a special device which measures the performance and distortion of my hearing aids. It graphs input to output quality of reproduction. Does such equipment exist for studio speakers, headphones or custom in ear monitors?

Comment: May be an electronics stack exchange question

Answer (score 1):

These days the most popular equipment is a calibrated microphone, interface, computer, and special software.

http://sonarworks.com/ is one good example but there are many, depending on the specific needs.